# Check state on more UISwitch´s at the same time

Tags: objective-c, uiswitch

I have a simpel  view with 5 UISwitch´s   and i want to make sure that only 4 can me set to off at the same time, how du i check more in one " if "  i tried this  and it just shows the alertview overtime i use the switch:

```
if (ishockeySwitch.state == NO | basketBallSwitch.state == NO | amrFootBallSwitch.state == NO | handBallSwitch.state == NO ) {



    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sofabold" message:@"Det er ikke en god ide, at fravælge alle sportsgrene." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [av show];

   [ soccerSwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];
}else {
   // ........ do some stuff ...........
}
```

Comment: updated it  here must have copied before editing the names .... but same outcome

Comment: To clarify, you want to show the alert if all 5 switches are set to off. correct? As long as one is set to on, you don't want the alert, correct?

Answer (score 0):

> if (ishockeySwitch.state == NO | ishockeySwitch.state == NO| ishockeySwitch.state == NO | ishockeySwitch.state == NO )

You are always comparing the same object ishockeySwitch to NO. All you UISwitch should be declared in differents objects.

```
if (ishockeySwitch1.state == NO || ishockeySwitch2.state == NO|| ishockeySwitch3.state == NO || ishockeySwitch4.state == NO ) 
{
   // DO SOME STUFF
}
```

Comment: even you did the same :P

Comment: You want `||` (logical OR), not `|` (bitwise OR).

Comment: And do not compare `BOOL` values against `YES` or `NO`. Use `if (someBool)` to see if it is YES, or use `if (!someBool)` to see if it is NO.

Comment: @rmaddy it absolutely changes anything and it's not the point here. I always use it like you said, it was just to show him what's wrong in his code. PS. Sorry for the mistake with the OR operator, just copied-pasted too quickly :/

Comment: Also, the logic here is all wrong. Your code will "do some stuff" even if all of the switches are off. In that case, the alert should be shown. It also will "do some stuff" if `ishockeySwitch1` is off regardless of any other switch. That's no good.

Comment: No not all, I just showed to @Skovie what was wrong in his code, I'm not going to write all his code at his place. You are completely confused between OR and AND operators. My code is exactly the same as you except as he did in his code, I said if one of the switch is off you "do some stuff" and I didn't add the else statement which I think he is big enough to add it himself depending of the behavior he wants.

Comment: I'm not confused at all. Your answer's logic is :) The OP wants the alert only if all switches are off. The only time your answer shows the alert is when all switches are on. This is the opposite of what the OP wants. Our code is not the same. My code says to "do some stuff" as long as one switch is on. Your code says to "do some stuff" as long as one switch is off.

Comment: haha you make me laugh. I said that my code do the same as you except it does it when the switch is off. I never said that my code shows the alert when the switches are all off. I've just took his code to have the same behavior following his requirements, that's all. Anyway, that's not the place to speak about it :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that what you are asking is how to show the alert only if all of the switches are off. In other words, don't show the alert if any switch is on. Assuming that is correct, the easiest logic is the following:

```
if (ishockeySwitch.on || basketBallSwitch.on || amrFootBallSwitch.on || handBallSwitch.on) {
    // At least one is on, do some stuff
} else {
    // All are off, show the alert
}
```

Also note the use of `||` (logical OR) instead of `|` (bitwise OR).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping out  i nedded  ||  and then i cud only make it work if i check is the switch isOn like below :

```
 if ([ishockeySwitch isOn ]|| [ basketBallSwitch isOn ]|| [amrFootBallSwitch isOn] || [handBallSwitch isOn]) {
    // At least one is on, do some stuff



} else {
    // All are off, show the alert


}
```